Laplacian of a rank two tensor in curvilinear coordinate
Could some one post the formula (or a reference) on laplacian of a rank two tensor in curvilinear coordinate? I have spent hours looking for it with no success. in particular, I found two contradicting formulas one in mathworld and the other one from internet.
Mathworld suggests the following formula

and I also found the following one somewhere else

The second one seems more reasonable to me as it has terms with two christoffel symbols (I think such terms would appear in the laplacian).
I really appreciate it if someone could help. I think it could be helpful to others too.

The mathworld formula is notoriously wrong.

@KurtG. Thanks! Any chance you know a reference that writes down all these terms?

I don't. Given the mathworld fiasco every such reference should be checked anyway. Cumbersome but doable.

@KurtG. Could you guide me how to do it? In your answer, how can I calculate the first term for example? It would be very helpful if you could show me how to calculate one of the terms

You will learn more when you try it yourself. The first term $A_{\mu\nu,;,\lambda,\kappa}$ is the only one where we still need to do a bit of work. This is the $\kappa$-th partial derivative of (A).

@KurtG. I have some easy questions for you. In your formula $A_{ij;λ}= A_{ij,λ}-...$, does $,\lambda$ mean derivative respect to the coordinate without scaling? For example, if $\lambda=\theta$, is the partial derivative respect to theta without the scaling or do I need to add the scaling $1/r$ too?

There is no scaling. Just plain partial derivatives denoted by the comma.

@KurtG. but in your formula (A), the first term on the right hand side must have the scaling 1/r (in polar coordinate and for $\lambda$ related to the angular part) for example it should be $A_{\mu \nu,\lambda}=(\partial_{\theta} A_{\mu \nu})/r$. Am I right?

No. You are wrong. That factor $1/r$ comes from the inverse metric $g^{\lambda\kappa},$ not from a partial derivatve.
